# Signs for Traditional Mandarin comming back as technology grows?

Tags: technology

We all know that the simplified Mandarian is much faster when handwriting. Yet future is obviously more and more filled with electronical typing rather than handwriting. This closes the problem with the difficulty and speed of writing and so are there any signs that we'll be comming back to the traditional Mandarin?

Comment: No. in the mainland of China, we still use simplified Chinese. However in HongKong, Marcow or Taiwan, Traditional Chinese is used.

Comment: Before people talk about typing it, kids need to learn it and speed-write it. So most probably Mandarin will still be the mainstream in future. In  history, Chinese took many forms, no matter good or bad those transitions were concerned, the mainstream seldom step back. Just like Koreans won't come back to use Chinese, which they had been using for most of its history, as the technology grows.

Answer (score 1):

No, and a definite no. Although there are voices about restoring traditional Chinese, these proposals are considered unpopular and expensive. Even top-ranked students of Chinese literature are unable to pass a basic traditional Chinese test. Even if the computer technology is advanced enough to fully replace handwriting, people are too used to simplified Chinese and will not bother changing the writing system again.

See this page:[Wikipedia: Debate on Traditional and Simplified Chinese Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debate_on_traditional_and_simplified_Chinese_characters)

Comment: I had the impression that most educated Chinese can read both standards, even though they can usually only handwrite in one of them.

Comment: Exactly for the first half. Not quite for the second half.

Comment: Exactly for which first half? "that most educated Chinese can read both standards"? In your answer you wrote that "Even top-ranked students of Chinese literature are unable to pass a basic traditional Chinese test". I'm pretty confused now.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Their test is a writing test.

Comment: Ah, I see. But the OP is asking if Traditional Chinese could become popular now that people usually type text on electronic devices. So the fact that they can't write it by hand is not really a problem.

Comment: Technically it is not. But that doesn't mean restoring Traditional Chinese is probable in the future.